# Get UserProfile / Information after successful authentication

Tags: shiro, pac4j

I will do another try, maybe I get an answer from someone who has knowledge in Pac4j.

I have a simple question for Pac4j.

I'm using Keycloak as Auth Provider.

After successful login I would like to store some information in e.g. a Session Bean:

- User Information
- call a function, e.g. UserLog (user have been login in the application)
- Set Language (information are coming from database)
- Set Permission (Permission are stored in application), I need to set this to the Shiro object

My main issue is currently, how can I get the User Information from Keycloak after Login?

Do I need to change anything in the `shiro.ini`? If yes, how?

My scenario would be:

- Get username from Keycloak (emailaddress)
- Call in my database a query to get the mapping between Keycloak user and application User
- Based on the user set in my Session Bean some information....

So the best way would be e.g. to define in my `shiro.ini` a class.
Inside the class I will get the User Information from Keycloak (especially the email address).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use pac4j alone, you don't need Shiro except for a Shiro legacy apps.

If you need to use the appropriate pac4j implementation for your webapp: https://www.pac4j.org/implementations.html

In any case, after a successful authentication at Keycloak thanks to pac4j(+Shiro), you will get the authenticated user in the pac4j(+Shiro) security context.

With pac4j, you can create an authorization generator to query your database and adapt the profile as needed: https://www.pac4j.org/5.7.x/docs/clients.html#2-compute-roles-and-permissions